Correct approach for a datamodel and viewmodel to live side by side in MVVM
I have a datamodel which I want to base a datagrid in a win-ui application on. Normally I would just define the datagrid on the viewmodel, but what would be the correct approach if I want to use the datamodel together with viewmodel according to MVVM? It is important that I do not alter the datamodel as it will be used for other projects.

I suggest you could refer to the Doc:The MVVM pattern The view model isolates the view from the model, and allows the model to evolve independently of the view.

I suggest you could refer to the Doc: The MVVM pattern. The view model isolates the view from the model, and allows the model to evolve independently of the view.
